# Defining Parameters using Spatially Constrained Multivariate Clustering of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, clustering, spatial-cluster

I have a point shapefile with 51673 features. I am trying to cluster them using the Spatially Constrained Multivariate Clustering tool in ArcGIS Pro. After reading through the documentation, I'm confused about how to define the parameters properly to get just 5 clusters that contain around the same number of points.

I thought to put 10,000 as the minimum number per cluster, and then specify the number of constraints as 5. However I get an error when I try to run this:

> ERROR 110122: Constraint Error: Unable to solve the tool based on the
>   Minimum/Maximum Constraints.  Failed to execute (Spatially Constrained
>   Multivariate Clustering).

I also tried defining the maximum number as 10,000 - but this gave me 9 clusters in which the distribution of features was unequal within the groups (and none of clusters actually got close to the maximum count of 10k). Again, ideally I want 5 clusters containing a similar number of features.

How could I modify the parameters so the tool gives me this back?

[image]